# "Interesting" Homomorphisms into $\text{Aut}(H)$, for $H\unlhd G$

Tags: group-theory

In preparation for first qualifiers, I've been staring at two problems from Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter* $0$, which state the following (these are problems $7.10$ and $8.25$ respectively if you have the text):

> $1$. For $\gamma_g\in\text{Inn}(G)$, $H\unlhd G$ is equivalent to $\gamma_g(H)\subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$, and there exists an interesting homomorphism from $\text{Inn}(G)$ to $\text{Aut}(H)$.

This I'm ok with. Clearly $H\unlhd G$ is equivalent to $\gamma_g(H) = gHg^{-1} = H$, and from here it's easy to show that the restriction $\gamma_g|_H\in\text{Aut}(H)$ for all $g\in G$. At this point I guess the interesting homomorphism is:
$$\phi:\text{Inn}(G)\to\text{Aut}(H),\quad\quad \phi(\gamma_g) = \gamma_g|_H.$$

> $2$. Let $H\unlhd G$ and let $H$ be abelian. Then there exists an interesting homomorphism from $G/H$ to $\text{Aut}(H)$.

Here is where I am confused. Of course we can define the homomorphism 
$$\psi:G/H\to\text{Aut}(H),\quad\quad \psi(gH) = \gamma_g|_H.$$
But the fact that this is a homomorphism doesn't rely on the fact that $H$ is abelian, since for all $x\in H$,
\begin{align}
\notag \psi(g_1g_2H)(x) &= \gamma_{g_1g_2}|_H(x)\\ 
\notag &= g_1g_2x(g_1g_2)^{-1} = g_1g_2xg_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}\\ 
\notag &= (\gamma_{g_1}|_H\circ\gamma_{g_2}|_H)(x)\\
\notag &= (\psi(g_1H)\circ\psi(g_2H))(x).
\end{align}

So I'm inclined to believe that this is not the homomorphism he is referring to. I can even define $f:G/H\to\text{Inn}(G),\ f(gH)=\gamma_g$ so that the appropriate diagram commutes. My question is this:

Are there other homomorphisms from $G/H$ and $\text{Inn}(G)$ to $\text{Aut}(H)$ that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a general normal subgroup $H$, $$gH \mapsto \gamma_g|_H$$ is not a well-defined homomorphism: to define such a map, you need to use the fact that $H$ is abelian.

More precisely, given that $H$ is abelian, we can show that $H$ is contained in the kernel of the map $G \to Aut(H)$ given by part (1). Hence the map factors through the quotient $G/H$.

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling I missed something, and that's it. That clears everything up. Thanks!